# How do you say the numbers from 1001-1009?

Tags: number

I know that for the numbers in the hundreds ending in "01" to "09" you use 零, such as

- 103 一百零三
- 509 五百零九

and so forth. Omitting the 零 here would change the meaning (一百三 = 130, 五百九 = 590).

How about numbers in the thousands ending in "001" to "009"? For example, how do you say 1001? Is it 一千零一 or 一千零零一？

Similarly, for 10001, is it 一万零一 or 一万零零零一?
Is 100000001 一亿零一 or 一亿零零零零零零零一?

Comment: You got it right.  一千零一, or quite common 一零零一.  一万零一, rare but fine, 一零零零一. 一亿零一.

Comment: Similar to the IPv6 address, all the connected 0 can be compressed ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are counting things,

1001 apples 一千零一個蘋果

10001 apples 一万零一個蘋果

100001 apples 十萬零一個蘋果

There is no need to repeat the zero.

If you are reciting numbers (telephone number style), then it's

1001 一零零一

10001 一零零零一

100001 一零零零零一

although, as expected, the more zeros you have, the more cumbersome, and harder to understand, and may need further clarification. Same as in English.

For the year 1001, both 一千零一年 and 一零零一年 are acceptable.

Comment: If you’re reciting telephone numbers it may even become 幺洞洞幺. Years, though, would definitely be 一零零一.